# What are "finely subdivided" substances?

Tags: terminology

As in the title, what does it mean for a substance to be *finely subdivided*, or *finely grained*? For example:

> It is only in the cases for which the ratio area/volume is very large (for example, a *finely grained* substance) that the surface must also be  considered.

or:

> In the case of a system composed by two homogeneous substances, it will be possible to express the internal energy of the system as the sum of the energies of the two substances only if we can neglect the surface energy of the two substances where they are in contact. The surface energy can generally be neglected only if the two substances are not very *finely subdivided*; otherwise, it can play an important role.

Comment: Can you give a little more context for the second quote?

Comment: @BMS I've added the full quote. This is from Fermi's Thermodynamics and I suppose is referring to PVT systems.

Answer (score 2):

I can respond to your first quote about *finely grained.*

Roughly speaking, a finely grained substance is a collection of a large number of "small" objects. Think of sand. Large or course grained substances, on the other hand, are compased of many "large" objects.

Here's a picture of course- and fine-grained salt.

[image]

Note that one would indeed have a larger surface-area-to-volume ratio, even though they're made of the same stuff.

I suspect the distinction is somewhat relative and arbitrary. The course salt above might be considered fine-grained when compared to ever larger-sized pieces.

Hopefully someone else can address your *finely divided* phrasing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I hope someone can provide a similar concrete example for the case in the second quotation.